# Join multiple tables in microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

am fairly new to microservices and building couple of microservices and facing a typical situation which i have done in monoliths,
microservice A will provide functionality related to one entity (read and CRUD operations), it is responsible to provide data for this object to be shown on UI.
microservice B is a generic service which provides functionality around lookups (lookups meaning, we store different lookup values and just add the foreign key to the entity in Microservice A).
the use case: when i show data in the UI from microservice A, it needs to fetch lookup values from the entity in microservice B (lookups), we have filtering and sorting to do on the UI and the values for the column to be sorted are coming from microservice B.
Microservices are being build using Spring boot, and db connectivity is done using Spring data JPA over hibernate
In a monolith, i used to join both tables directly in my JPQL (@Query annotation) and fetch the desired result. Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this.

Comment: The question is about the data sources. Are you using 2 separate schemas for micro service A and B? If yes then you will need to sync their data in both the schemas and fetch them separately. If no then I assume A and B are using same schema and all the entity tables are under one hood. In that case your `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` mappings will fulfill your needs.

Comment: yes, A and B are using the same schema and if i understand correctly, we need to create the entity (lookups) in all the microservices that require this entity, am i correct in my understanding?

Comment: Yes correct because they share the same schema so if we create lookups for those entities or even if we copy them as it is, it will not affect the system. Because common entities are used in both A and B but only one of them is modifying it, other is only using it as read only to fetch data